# Open PSA: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied | postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, driver

I am trying to setup OpenPSA in my system... Using this [link](https://openpsa2.org/resources/installing-openpsa/).

I am using postgres as a database for this. I followed the initial steps & stuck with couple of errors of postgres. I tried couple of links to resolve this error. But, its not working. It shows this error when i execute the command and input the path to config file.

I am trying to execute this command:

```
 sudo ./vendor/bin/midgard-portable schema
```

[image]

I am giving the correct path to the config. file.

I am not able to find any clue regarding the error.

Here is my `midgard-portable-default.inc.php` file:

```
<?php
use midgard\portable\driver;
use midgard\portable\storage\connection;

$basedir = dirname(__DIR__);

require_once $basedir . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$schema_dirs = [$basedir . '/schemas/'];

$driver = new driver($schema_dirs, $basedir . '/var', '');

// CHANGE PARAMETERS AS REQUIRED:
$db_config = [
    'memory' => true,
    'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
];

connection::initialize($driver, $db_config, true);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify a password?

Comment: I didn't find the config file to put on the password.

Comment: The link you posted says, "Create a new database in your favorite tool, and save the connection information in `config/midgard-portable.inc.php`." Perhaps that is the correct place?

Comment: I posted the information... which was required i feel...Let me edit the question to show my config. file as well

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here (using the MySQL driver).
As the syntax of `config/midgard-portable.inc.php` does not seem to be documented, and there are no  instructions on how to specify a password.

I found the following sample in `openpsa/vendor/doctrine/orm/docs/en/reference/configuration.rst`:

```
    // the connection configuration
    $dbParams = array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user'     => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname'   => 'foo',
    );
```

Tried to duplicate the syntax and finally got the OpenPSA start page loading.
Steps to follow:

1. `cd config`
2. `cp ./midgard-portable-default.inc.php midgard-portable.inc.php`
3. edit the `midgard-portable.inc.php` by adding 3 lines of code (user, password and dbname) like this:

```
// CHANGE PARAMETERS AS REQUIRED:
$db_config = [
    'memory' => true,
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'db-username',
    'password' => 'db-password',
    'dbname'   => 'db-name',
];
```

*Previously tried the following steps (probably not necessary to follow), yet I'm leaving them here for reference:
The `./vendor/bin/openpsa-installer midgard2:setup` prompted for a username, password and DB name, and if I want to "Use existing configuration file midgard-portable.inc.php"
Specifying the parameters and refusing to use the existing file, got me moving forward. Instead of connection errors I got an "Unknown database" error.*